# On mobile site, when editing a question, I get told that it shouldn’t be mostly code and that it is an answer

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, mobile-web, error-message

Suggesting an edit adding code formatting to the code in a question, I got this error message

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

[image: A screenshot with the above message]

This is weird. First, I was editing a question but it said it was an answer; second, I don’t have any more details, because **I didn’t write the question**.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Happened to me recently and wasn't mobile but desktop site.

Comment: @john on desktop it tells me to add more details, but doesn’t say it’s an answer.

Comment: Yes, doesn't say it's an answer.

Comment: Does this happen on sites besides SO?

Comment: @V2Blast I don't really have a good way of testing it, hmm.

Comment: Well this is due to it being a suggested edit. A full edit on the post would likely not result in this warning. Also seeing you get this error message I doubt it is useful to edit the question at all. Seeing the poster didn't adhere to the rules you are now getting struck with, perhaps they even circumvented those rules by NOT using code formatting. (or they were ignorant of the function and the site didn't catch the low quality because of that)